# SQL Agent that runs SQL agents doesn't wait between steps

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL agent job that I want to have kicking off 4 other SQL agent jobs using the following:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'My Other Job'
```

Now each job is its own step, however, the job does not wait to see if the job finishes successfully, it just kicks off the next step, so all 4 are running at once.  As there a way to make it wait before it kicks off the next job?

Thanks

Comment: No, but there is probably a work-around for what you need to do.   Can't you just make the steps of the other jobs steps in your main job?

Comment: The 4 jobs are database restores across a network, so there is variability in their runtime.  I want to avoid overlap of running.

Comment: [This article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2008/11/27/Run-jobs-synchronously.aspx) contains a stored procedure that wraps up `sp_start_job` and will wait for the job to complete before exiting the procedure. You could use this to make your jobs run synchronously.

Comment: It seems you are not alone in this problem, and [a connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/434754/add-synchronous-wait-option-to-sp-start-job) was opened to make `sp_start_job` run synchronously, unfortunately this has been closed as won't fix. I think the only options are to create your own listener to keep checking if the job has finished, or to create a single job that combines all the steps of the separate jobs, neither are really ideal!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've waited before with this:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
while exists (select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
                inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a on j.job_id = a.job_id 
                where name = 'My Other Job' 
                and stop_execution_date is null and start_execution_date is not null)
begin
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';   
end
```

where you can pause for whatever makes sense. My job was relatively small, so I only waited 2 seconds between checking.

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Agent job step waits it receives a "success" message before going to the next step.  However, when that step is to call msdb.dbo.sp_start_job, it receives a "success" message as soon as the target job is started.   The message is saying "Yes, I successfully started the job".

There is no way to make it wait for completion of that job, if this is the method you use.

However, if you consolidate your five jobs into one job, and put the steps in the order that you want, each step will wait until the previous step is completed before starting.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I found this very helpful.